# Display multiple rows with one column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables.  Title and Order.  Title has title_num.  Order has title_num and order_num. Each title has many orders.

I would like to display title_num and all of its orders. But I would like to display it so that I display 1 title_num for multiple order_nums:

```
title_num| order_num
1          a
1          b
1          c
2          x
2          y
```

I would like it to look like:

```
title_num| order_num

1          a
           b
           c

2          x
           y
```

I've tried using left join to sort it by the title but that's where I'm stuck. Is it possible to display it like this?

```
select t.title_num, o.order_num
from title t
left join order o
on t.title_num=o.title_num
```

Comment: If you were using SQL*Plus for this then you could use the [`break`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve009.htm) functionality [described in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_six.htm#i1081534) to achieve this, including the gap between the values (e.g. `break on title_num nodup skip 1`). That doesn't seem to have been carried over to SQL Developer unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

*(Don't have enough rep to comment, so I'll give the options in an answer)*

You can't hide a result if its the same as the previous row. Instead, you would handle it in the code or report.

- If you are displaying it in a report, you would group the results in the report manager.
- If you are iterating in code, have a variable that keeps track of that column variable.

  Initialize the variable with a blank string. Then as you iterate the query's dataset:

  1. If the current row value is the same as the variable's value, display a blank. Otherwise, show the row value.
  2. Set the variable to the current row's value.

Comment: Yes, displaying it in the report itself was a lot easier than trying to get my SQL query to work. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help! (Cough Cough.. mark mine as answer ;) )

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the LAG function and a CASE statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LAG(title_num,1) OVER (PARTITION BY title_num ORDER BY order_num) IS NULL THEN title_num
              ELSE ' '
         END
      ,order_num
FROM Order
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08911/3/0)

Comment: I tried this first but I also had other parameters to display too so I give up on it.  Luckily I got it to work in my report somehow.  Thanks for your help though, I learned a lit bit more about my queries after trying to work this code though so it was still helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the window function (analytic function in Oracle parlance) [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions144.htm#i86310):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY title_num
                                    ORDER BY order_num) = 1 THEN
       title_num ELSE NULL END AS title_num
      ,order_num
FROM   ord o
ORDER  BY  o.title_num, order_num;
```

[**->SQLfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a56cc/3).

Why do you `JOIN` to `title` at all? Are there titles without order? Otherwise you can just omit it from the query.

Don't use reserved words like `order` as table names. I use `ord` instead in my solution.

Note how I table-qualify `o.title_num` in `ORDER BY` to refer to the input column, not the output column.

Comment: I was using join because I had more parameters from both tables that needed to be displayed.  But I think I got the results I wanted. After seeing your code I realize I was over thinking the problem.  Thanks.